# Facebook Connect OR Facebook Authorization using OAuth 2.0

Tags: facebook

I want to allow users to sign in using facebook as well to my website, since the recent release of new Facebook stuff, I am unsure which one to use. Previously, Facebook Connect was used. Now we have Facebook authorization feature, using the OAuth 2.0.

Please tell me which one to use? and Is Facebook Connect going to be obsolete?

I am new to Facebook Development.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Oauth2 because Facebook Connect is indeed obsolete. The following links helped me a lot to do it:

1 - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

2 - [how to post in facebook from my asp.net mvc 3 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313506/how-to-post-in-facebook-from-my-asp-net-mvc-3-website)

3 - [Architecture for merging multiple user accounts together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666267/architecture-for-merging-multiple-user-accounts-together)

4 - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Post-Publish-and-Share-content-on-users-FaceBook-Wall-using-Graph-API-in-ASPNet.aspx