# Architecture for merging multiple accounts and registering a user account

Tags: facebook, security, architecture, oauth, multiple-login

My question is almost the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666267/architecture-for-merging-multiple-user-accounts-together)

only difference is that  users has an option to register (provides his username and password).Users should only have one account registered, if the user has the same email I merged those accounts. and my application has another method for logging in which is via Facebook.

What I basically do is

- When The User visits the for site for the first time, he or she then
  gets created a User Account where the it only has Username ,password
  and mail address after that third-party identity record is created
  and then paired with the local account.however the Users table will
  have an empty Username and password, but the email will be filled
  with the users email that we have retrieved from the third party
  service provider

And the Second Scenario

- Users attempts Register to the site. check if email exist if the 
  email exist  but it is registered   using a third party account, Use
  the user populated form and insert it to the user  account paired
  with the third party account, in short if the users email exist in the database I
  will just merged the locally created account and the third party
  account.

Now my question is my approach secure and credible? if not what is the best way to merge accounts and at the same time if the user registers with the same email(the one from the third party account) and he has a third party account, those account would be merge?

Comment: Is it something like OpenID that you want to achieve?

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste yup that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The way I look at this, there is only one account. One email, one account period. There might be various attributes associated with that account, like for e.g. linked to a set of OAuth credentials etc. But fundamentally there is only one account. If your user has registered once using a social account and then try to register again on your site, send them over to the social site which they used to register the first time and ask them to login there. Then log them into your site automatically. If the user has an account with your site and then tries to register again with a social account, tell them that you already have an account on the site and ask them to login. IMHO, keeping separate accounts and trying to merge them is a messy idea.

Answer (score 3):

I would provide two sets of behavior, one when logged in and one when logged out.

When logged in, you provide the ability to link to new third-party accounts.  For example, you sign up with email address and password, then log in, then you can link your Facebook account.    To link your Facebook account you authorize with Facebook and then store the Facebook information in that user account record.

When logged out, you must log in with existing credentials.  If, when logged out, you try to create an account with an existing email address, you either prevent the log in, saying "an account with that email address already exists", or you immediately challenge the user to log in to merge the account (in which case it works like the logged in case when linking an external account, only with the order of authentication operations reversed).

In case it's not clear from the above, I recommend having a single user account and a way to record linkages between that account and external accounts.  You can do this in NoSQL buy just adding fields to the user document or you can do this relationally by having a table representing external accounts with a foreign key linking them to the user ID.

Comment: With twitter, they don't provide emails. Got any ideas on how to merge twitter and other oauth accounts?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, your choices are to forbid creating accounts with Twitter (can only add after logging in some other way), force new Twitter users to provide and email address as part of the sign-up flow, or risk Twitter users creating unintended duplicate accounts.

Comment: Could you tell me how you would identify unique twitter users? Through their name? That seems the only unique identifier that I can use. I mean like wheb the same twitter user logs in again.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, the Twitter handle (their `@name`) is unique, since that's how you follow them.   Twitter also provides a numeric ID that is unique.  The numeric ID is better because a person can change their Twitter handle but the ID number will stay the same AFAIK.

Comment: Would you allow user accounts to merge if both accounts have their own activity/history/... on the site? For example: me as a googleplus user has bought something on the website with a certain set of payment credentials. Me as a facebook user also bought something with different payment credentials. How do you merge those 2 ?

Comment: @jan, yes, I would allow user accounts to merge even if both accounts have their own activity/history/... on the site. Exactly how you merge them depends very much on how you represent accounts and related attributes. You may need to send the user through a manual merge process to resolve some conflicts (e.g. if the two accounts have different home telephone numbers) or you may just be able to transfer the transactions and attributes from one account to another.

Comment: @OldPro: Is this (manual) conflict-resolving merge irreversible? Do you still know which accounts were merged when? Or is it a matter of replacing user id's troughout the database?

Comment: @jan, it's whatever you build it to be. If it's a (regulated) banking app you need to provide a complete audit trail; you might end up creating a whole new (third) account. In the simplest case you'd just replace user IDs throughout the database. You can look at how StackExchange handles merging duplicate accounts for an intermediate level of complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Beware not to use oAuth 2.0 !
The [lead author himself resigned](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/) as it's not as safe as the 1.0 version.

You should prefer oAuth 1.0 or OpenID.

You can also have a look at [Persona from Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/)