# OAuth2 Merging Multiple Accounts from Twitter andother services

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

According to this question: [Architecture for merging multiple accounts and registering a user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105112/architecture-for-merging-multiple-accounts-and-registering-a-user-account)

Various answers have said that using email is a good way of establishing correspondence between different accounts and then doing automatic merging for multiple account sign in.

However, twitter is a major provider that does not provide email through their oauth API.

How can we reliably and automatically establish a correspondence between a twitter account and for example Google, Facebook, Github... etc accounts? So that we can auto-merge those accounts.

I'm writing a library to help in this, so it's not really useful to say do it manually, since I would like to provide options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no secure-way to automatically do it, I implemented an application with local account/Twitter.Facebook/Google and I didn't have other choice.

I suggest you to allow your users to register with one method (local account, Twitter, Facebook, Google...) and create a page in "My account" that allow them to associate other accounts.

In Twitter a user can be identified by either a name or a key, you have no way to know them unless you explicitly ask them to the user.

Moreover now in Twitter 1.1 you have to redirect your user to Twitter to approve your application and then you get the OAuth token and security key. As you can see there must be an interaction with Twitter, at least if you need to perform some restricted queries on his behalf (e.g. create a Tweet).