# Ask for user Twitter mail with TWTRShareEmailViewController (Fabric Twitter SDK) in Swift

Tags: ios, email, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'd like to request the user's Twitter mail. On https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/request-email we can see the code in Obj-C but I need it in Swift and I can't translate it. Does anyone know how, please?

Here's the Obj-C code:

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {
    TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController =
                [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
                 initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"Email %@, Error: %@", email, error);
    }];
    [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                                            animated:YES
                                            completion:nil];
} else {
  // TODO: Handle user not signed in (e.g.
  // attempt to log in or show an alert)
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you took look at this http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/twitter-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: Thanks for answering but it's a tutorial using Social Framework, I'm using Fabric. And it's not about getting the user's mail but writing a tweet with an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should roughly translate the above Objective-C to Swift:

```
if (Twitter.sharedInstance().session() != nil) {
        if let shareEmailViewController = TWTRShareEmailViewController(completion: {
            (email: String!, error: NSError!) in
            if (email != nil) {
                print("\(email)")
            } else {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }) {
            self.presentViewController(shareEmailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        print("User not logged in")
    }
```

Comment: I think it works! It's returning an error but the code works. I guess all that is left for me to do now is to be whitelisted by Twitter. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. It returned an error indicated I had to get the proper authorizations setup for my app. Good luck!