# Error warning while implementing TWTRShareEmailViewController

Tags: ios, swift, email, twitter, twitter-fabric

```
if (Twitter.sharedInstance().session() != nil) {
    if let shareEmailViewController = TWTRShareEmailViewController(completion: {
        (email: String!, error: NSError!) in
        if (email != nil) {
            print("\(email)")
        } else {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }) {
        self.presentViewController(shareEmailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
} else {
    print("User not logged in")
}
```

I'm getting the following error warning `Cannot convert value of type '(String!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type 'TWTRShareEmailCompletion?'` when I use the above code block?

I'm trying to access twitter user's email through the above code block. Can anyone please help?

Comment: When you get code directly from another SO thread, you should link to that one, giving context and making it easier for other to try to answer you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679652/ask-for-user-twitter-mail-with-twtrshareemailviewcontroller-fabric-twitter-sdk

Comment: Note also that the anser by Mark Thistle in the thread I linked to above was using Swift < Swift 2.0.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take care from next time.