# Please compare Facebook Connect vs Facebook (OpenID+Oauth)?

Tags: php, oauth, facebook, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Connect OR Facebook Authorization using OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888492/facebook-connect-or-facebook-authorization-using-oauth-2-0)

I am getting very confused in the 2 :

> - Facebook Connect
> - Facebook (OpenID + OAuth)

In my mind, we can do the same things with both. Authenticate the user and access the private data of the user after authorization.

So, Are they different ?

If yes, then what is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[asking google](http://www.google.de/#hl=en&q=difference+between+facebook+connect+and+openid) for "difference between facebook connect and openid" gives you [this great artice](http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2010/11/04/facebook-connect-oauth-and-openid-the-differences-and-the-future/) as one of the first results, wich should answer all of your questions.

in general: yes, there's a difference. facebook connect offers more information than using openID and...

> [...] Instead of just offering credentials, Facebook wanted to offer friend
>   access and dynamics to the privacy of the information that simply
>   wasn’t possible with the other standards.

**EDIT :**
if this didn't help you, try to search on SO for questions about the same topic, there are some with really great answers:

- [What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)
- [Facebook Connect OR Facebook Authorization using OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888492/facebook-connect-or-facebook-authorization-using-oauth-2-0)
- ...

Comment: I saw the article, may be I didn't read it properly. But you missed Oauth, with that you can access Facebook friends. 
So, that doesn't draws the difference in my opinion. So, I am reading the article again - and see if you can find the difference.

Comment: The article doesn't help, since it doesn't shows the difference.

Comment: you're right, there's no table wich exactly shows the difference for each piece of information, but it explains the differnce and why those different implementations of "nearly the same thing" exist. if you just want to see the difference in the data you can get, implement both in a little project for testing and compare yourself, this shouldn't take longer than 20 minutes.

Comment: Well, in these social stuff data is not all, its more of the flow, and  number of redirect + the data. Brute-forcing something may not yield 100% correct info. :(

Comment: Can you promote the question in some way ?